# How to use not equal operator in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the structure of the document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5548f1cc0dcd6bd925a71ae2"), //document id
    "messages" : [
        {
            "subject" : "NEW ++ SUBJECT",
            "from" : ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5548f1cc0dcd6bd925a71ae3"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-05-05T16:37:32.832Z"),
            "read" : false,
            "message" : "FIRST MESSAGE",
            "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"),
                ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
            ]
        },
        {
            "subject" : "dfgsd",
            "from" : ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),//logged In USer
            "_id" : ObjectId("5548f1df0dcd6bd925a71ae4"),
            "created" : ISODate("2015-05-05T16:37:51.455Z"),
            "read" : false,
            "message" : "rdfgdgfd",
            "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),//logged In USer
                ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
            ]
        }
    "participants" : [
        ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),//logged In USer
        ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c31"),
        ObjectId("5530af38576214dd3553331c")
    ],
    "__v" : 3

}
```

I want to get the message objects of the messages array whose 'read' value is 'false' & 'from' is NOT EQUAL TO LOGGED IN USER ( here logged in user is 5534b2992a104ed914435c98). And the 'participants' array of the document has to contain logged in user id(5534b2992a104ed914435c98). Here is the query I tried.

```
db.conversations.find({participants:ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98'),'messag‌​es.read':false,'messages.from':{$ne:ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98')}}).prett‌​y().
```

Basically I am trying to get the count of unread messages.
I am very new to mongodb/mongoose. Please correct me if you find something wrong in the question.

Comment: So in your above example nothing would be returned? I'm also a bit confused about how you are storing your data (what does this document represent?)  Seems like `participants` at the end should have `31c` as well.

Comment: _Please get me a query which gives the required result._??? Can you show us what you have attempted, seems like you have been posting similar questions without feedback on the answers provided.

Comment: @ExplosionPills : Yes right, I have modified now .

Comment: @chridam : Sorry for the late feedback . And here is the code I tried.

db.conversations.find({participants:ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98'),'messages.read':false,'messages.from':{$ne:ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98')}}).pretty()
Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to get the number of unread messages based on the criteria that the messages array whose 'read' value is 'false' & 'from' is NOT EQUAL TO LOGGED IN USER (here logged in user is `5534b2992a104ed914435c98`) and the `'participants'` array of the document has to contain logged in user id `5534b2992a104ed914435c98`, then the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** approach should help you to get the desired result.

The aggregation pipeline should have the first pipeline stage a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) query which satisfies the above. This filters the documents that are necessary to be processed further down the pipeline stream.

For a solution that does not use the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator to flatten the messages array first before processing, consider the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operators as follows:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),
            "messages.read" : false,
            "messages.from" : { "$ne": ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98') }
        }
    },    
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "unread_messages": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$messages",
                        "as": "msg",
                        "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$not": [ "$$msg.read" ] },
                                { "$ne": ["$$msg.from", ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98')]}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
]

db.conversations.aggregate(pipeline)
```

If you are using a driver that does not support the above operators, consider having the next pipeline stage after the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) as the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation which is done to deconstruct the `messages` array so that you can output a document for each element.

A further filtering using [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator is required on the deconstructed messages to allow only those messages which meet the earlier criteria to be processed further down the pipeline.

This piece of operation is necessary for the next pipeline stage, the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator which groups the incoming documents by a specified identifier expression and applies the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator expression to each group so that you can get the total number of documents in the group.

The last stage uses the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator to reshape the final result document in the stream by suppressing the _id field and adds a new field `unread_messages` that depicts the total number of messages with the `read` field value as false.

The final aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),
            "messages.read" : false,
            "messages.from" : { "$ne": ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98') }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$messages"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),
            "messages.read" : false,
            "messages.from" : { "$ne": ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98') }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "unread_messages": "$count"
        }

    }
]
```

You can use this in your Mongoose aggregation as follows:

```
Conversations.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(res); // [ { unread_messages: 34 } ] <-- this is a made up value :-)
});)
```

Or using the aggregation pipeline builder:

```
Conversations.aggregate()
    .match({
            "participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),
            "messages.read" : false,
            "messages.from" : { "$ne": ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98') }
    })
    .unwind("messages")
    .match({
            "participants": ObjectId("5534b2992a104ed914435c98"),
            "messages.read" : false,
            "messages.from" : { "$ne": ObjectId('5534b2992a104ed914435c98') }
    })
    .group({ "_id": null, "unread_messages": { "$sum": 1 } })
    .select("-id unread_messages")
    .exec(function (err, res) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(res); // [ { unread_messages: 34 } ] <-- this is a made up value :-)
});
```